# v-text-field rules: required is other variable equals given value

Tags: vuetify.js

How to set a rule which says: `Required` if and only if `foo == 10` or  `foo == 20`

```
<v-text-field
  label="Bar"
  :value="bar"
  :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Required']"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71550865-textfield-validation-example-snicd0?file=/src/components/Example.vue

Remember that the conditional statement that you write in your vuetify rules, decides if the input is valid. So in order to show the `Required` message if and only if the value is 10 or 20. You'll need to create your rule denying that condition.

So, if the input (v) is not equal to 10 and 20, then, the input is valid, other way, show the message `Required`.

Also in this example I  convert the input value to a number, because when you type a number in a `v-text-field` gets converted to a string.

```html
<v-text-field
    label="Bar"
    :value="bar"
    :rules="[(v) => (Number(v) !== 10 && Number(v) !== 20) || 'Required']"
/>
```